# Mongodb 3.4 on 64bit Ubuntu 16.04 mongodb-27017.sock ERROR

Tags: mongodb

There are a few posts related Mongodb 3.2, but when I attempted to install 3.4 the startup does not occur. Instead an unusual error appears in the log file (shown at the very end of the listing).
Is this perhaps because of an older version that was installed?
I did do an apt-get remove and purge.
Can anybody suggest why the error appears?

I followed the steps below, as outlined [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/?_ga=1.133134733.261063209.1486580681#install-mongodb-community-edition),

```
$ sudo apt-get remove  mongodb*
$ sudo apt-get purge  mongodb*
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/mongodb
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/log/mongodb
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
$ echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
..
..
E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated

$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-org # removed -y to get it going
..
..


Setting up mongodb-org (3.4.2) ...
$ sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
$ sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb # modified ownership in view of what is stated on the mongodb installation note

$ # created the following file
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service 
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Service 3.4
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# startup
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo service mongod start

# nothing happens, I then viewed the log file and the following error appears:
$ cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
2017-02-08T22:08:26.155+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2017-02-08T22:08:26.159+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=11384 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=12g
2017-02-08T22:08:26.159+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.2
2017-02-08T22:08:26.159+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b
2017-02-08T22:08:26.159+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-02-08T22:08:26.159+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-02-08T22:08:26.159+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-02-08T22:08:26.159+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-02-08T22:08:26.159+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-02-08T22:08:26.159+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-02-08T22:08:26.159+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-02-08T22:08:26.159+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log", quiet: true } }
2017-02-08T22:08:26.178+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Operation not permitted
```

Comment: I modified the sock file ownership as follows `$ sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`. Once restarted the log file now indicates: `2017-02-08T22:54:13.414+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017`. The service however has not started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mcgraddy, thanks, that was helpful indeed. Creating the directory and copying the service file was the answer.

```
$ sudo cp /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service

$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /data
```

I had to change ownership for /data. 
Starting the service and viewing status shows everything is running as expected:

```
$ sudo service mongod start
$ sudo systemctl status mongodb
● mongodb.service - MongoDB Database Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-02-09 13:26:07 GMT; 9min ago
 Main PID: 1184 (mongod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service
           └─1184 /usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

Feb 09 13:26:07 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Service.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Operation not permitted
```

That means the mongod process was started by root user.So you can just remove the `sock` file or run this command to fix this issue :

```
sudo chown `whoami` /tmp/mongodb-*.sock
```

Make sure that the port you assign needs to be accessible and not blocked by your firewall and then just restart the mongod process.

> The waiting for connections message in the console output indicates
>   that the mongod.exe process is running successfully.

You can check out [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#verify-that-mongodb-has-started-successfully).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I now see `I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017` in the tail of the log as you mentioned, but when I run `sudo systemctl status mongodb` the output appears as `● mongodb.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)`. Can you suggest which file it is referring to since there were no issues with the installation?

Comment: @alortimor. Check out your config file,make sure you have created the `/data/db` folder,and run this `systemctl enable mongod.service`